# Should Javascript ES6 Classes be Used as React State?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, es6-class

Should ES6 classes be used directly as React state?

I want to define an ES6 class that:

1. Has member variables that will be displayed on the frontend. (changes to them trigger re-renders)
2. Has methods that sync those member variables with my backend periodically as they change.

However, calling `setState` does not appear to diff class members, at least as far as I can tell.

Using the following class:

```js
class Document{
  constructor(){
    this.title = "";
    this.body = "";
  }


  syncWithDatabase = async () => {
    // do some logic to update the database 
  }

}
```

And this component:

```js
// import Document from "...";

export default function Sandbox() {
  const [document, setDocument] = useState(new Document());
  const [renderTrigger, setRenderTrigger] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{document.title}</div>
      <div>{document.body}</div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          document.title = 'Some Default Title';
          document.body = 'lorem text';
          document.syncWithDatabase(); // being able to take this type of action in this way is why I'm trying to use classes. 
          setDocument(document);
        }}
      >
        Set Canned Data
      </button>

      <div>Render trigger is: {renderTrigger ? 'true' : 'false'}</div>
      <button onClick={() => setRenderTrigger(true)}>Force Render</button>

   </div>
  );
}
```

Clicking the first button will set the title and body on the instance of `Document` held react state, but it **will not** update the UI.

Clicking the second button to force a re-render in a way that I am confident will work makes the updated members of `document` render out, even though they didn't when `setDocument` is called.

Creating a new object with `new Document()` and passing it `setDocument` **WILL** trigger a re-render. So I'm thinking that react isn't doing a deep compare or is seeing that the reference to the `Document` object has not changed, and therefore not re-rending.

So, is it possible to change an object's members, pass that object to a setState hook and have it update the UI, without creating an entirely new object? Or should I avoid doing what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: I'd avoid doing that. Modifying an instance's members doesn't modify the instance itself, so an equality check such as `===` is going to identify your instances as the same thing each time.

Comment: Actually your document should be a custom hook. The state should only contain data, and should not be mutated

Comment: You should [not mutate state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#bailing-out-of-a-state-update) in React.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **can** (but probably shouldn't, see below) use an object created by a constructor function (which is what `document` is in your code) as state. What you **can't** do is directly modify it as you are here (see [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly)):

```
document.title = 'Some Default Title'; // <=== INCORRECT
document.body = 'lorem text';          // <=== INCORRECT
document.syncWithDatabase();
setDocument(document);                 // <=== INCORRECT
```

Instead, you'd need to create a *new* document object

```
const newDoc = new Document();
newDoc.title = 'Some Default Title';
newDoc.body = 'lorem text';
newDoc.syncWithDatabase();
setDocument(newDoc);
```

That said, when using the `useState` hook, you're usually better off keeping your state variables discrete (having one for `title` and one for `body`), so that changing one doesn't require also changing the other (unless, of course, they *always* change together). The documentation discusses that [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-one-or-many-state-variables); here's one quote:

> ...**we recommend to split state into multiple state variables based on which values tend to change together.**

*(their emphasis)*

Comment: Is there a risk of code becoming inefficient when creating a new object on every change?  Say if the body was very large? Is there a react provided alternative to useState that is better suited to what I'm am asking for? The real Document Object I'm trying to represent has 14 member variables. I'm not excited about having 14 state variables in my component. Although that's how I'm doing it now.

Comment: @HunterHeston - JavaScript engines are ***very*** fast at creating objects, and very clever about reclaiming memory, but there's always a *chance* it could become a problem. If you want to have your state grouped together in an object, though, that's pretty much your only choice since the setter provided by `useState` will ignore you if you provide the same object again. (I can think hacky ways to force re-rendering while avoiding creating new objects, but I'd be leery of doing it without a ***lot*** of testing [repeating that testing every time React has a dot release].)

Comment: Nope, I do not want to do anything to circumvent react. Thanks, your answer makes a lot of sense and answers several questions I have been trying to figure out recently.